# Minimizing the surface area of a cylinder WITHOUT derivatives?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, optimization

I’m trying to help my younger sibling with an optimization homework problem, he is in pre-calculus. How would you go about solving the following without using derivatives?

*A food packaging company wants to make cylindrical cans that hold 1 liter (1000 cm^3) of their product. What dimensions will enable them to use a minimum amount of material?*

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as just graphing the surface area function? (You should be able to express height or radius as a function of the other, making graphing relatively easy.)

Comment: Hint: Express area $A$ and volume $V$ in terms of radius $r$ and height $h$. Rewrite expression of $A$ to the form you can apply AM $\ge$ GM.

Comment: You haven't made it clear whether this is an open can (i.e. consists of a curved side and a bottom), or a closed can, with both top and bottom.

Answer (score 6):

Given: $\displaystyle \pi r^{2} h\ =\ K$ and we have to find minimum of $\displaystyle 2\pi r( r +h)$
this boils down to finding minimum of $\displaystyle 2r^{2} +2rh\ =\ 2r^{2} +rh+rh$
Applying AM-GM: $\displaystyle 2r^{2} +rh+rh\ \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{2r^{2} *rh*rh} \ \ =\ 3\sqrt[3]{2r^{4} h^{2}} \ \ =\ 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{2K^{2}}{\pi ^{2}}}$
But multiplying this back with $ $$\displaystyle \pi $ to get back the surface area:
we get
Minimum surface area for given constant volume for cylinder $\displaystyle \ 3\sqrt[3]{2\pi K^{2}}$

Comment: Note that in this case, $h=2r$, or the height equals the _diameter_.

Answer (score 0):

For a given volume $V$ you could rewrite the area $A$ as a function of the radius $r$.

$$\begin{array}{}
V & =& \pi r^2 h \\
A & =& 2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h
\end{array}$$

where $h$ is the height of the can.

If you rewrite the first equation $h = V/(\pi r^2)$ and fill it into the second equation then you get

$$A = 2\pi r^2 + 2\frac{V}{r}$$

By plotting this we can find the radius for which the area is a minimum (and I guess that this is the trick that students learn first).

[image: example plot]

The plot helps to gain the intuition that the minimum is the point where the slope is zero (and that this is how one could find the minimum). But we could find that point without formally using a derivative (although effectively it looks much like it and it might be easier to learn about derivatives).

Consider the minimum radius $r_m$ for which $A/(2\pi) =  r^2 + \frac{V/\pi}{r}$ is minimized, then for any different radius $r_m + \Delta$ we must have a larger area if $r_m$ is the minimum. We can try to solve the expression for the difference which must be above zero for any value of $\Delta$

$$\begin{array}{rcl} 0 &\leq& (r_m+\Delta)^2 + \frac{V/\pi}{r_m+\Delta} -  (r_m)^2 - \frac{V/\pi}{r_m} \\
& \leq& 2 r_m  \Delta + \Delta^2 - \frac{V/\pi\Delta}{r_m \Delta + r_m^2}   \\
& \leq& 3 r_m^2  \Delta^2 + 2 r_m^3 \Delta + r_m\Delta^3 - V/\pi\Delta  \\
& \leq&\Delta(r_m\Delta^2 + 3 r_m^2  \Delta + 2 r_m^3   - V/\pi)  \\
\end{array}$$

The part in brackets is a polynomial and in order for the product with $\Delta$ to be positive, the polynomial must have a zero in the point $\Delta = 0$. From that it follows that

$$r_m = \left(\frac{V}{2\pi}\right)^{1/3}$$

Comment: There seems to be a units error in your final result: the lhs has units of volume, and the rhs has units of length.

Comment: @BrianChandler that was a typo while writing $2 r_m^3   - V/\pi =0$ in a different form.

Comment: I thought so, but it seemed more reliable to let you fix it!

Answer (score 0):

A "product" is normally sold in supermarkets etc, so I assume the can has both top and bottom. Let's call the radius of the base $r$, and the height $h$.

Instead of considering a constant volume and finding the minimum amount of material, I will consider a fixed amount of material, and look for the maximum volume. The optimal shape is obviously the same whichever way you do it.

Now think about the can for some $r$ and $h$. Consider an infinitesimal increase $\epsilon$ in the radius. The extra material for top and bottom will be $2 . 2\pi r . \epsilon$ (each of top and bottom needs an extra flat ring of material of length $2\pi r$ and width $\epsilon$). The material used for the sides will have to be reduced by the same amount; suppose the height is reduced by $\delta$. Then the area of the strip used for the sides goes from $2 \pi r h$ to $2 \pi (r+\epsilon)(h-\delta)$, so getting longer by a strip $2 \pi \epsilon h$, and narrower by $2 \pi r \delta$. (Because these are infinitesimals, we can ignore anything with them multiplied together.)

So the zero change is:
$2 . 2\pi r . \epsilon + 2 \pi \epsilon - 2 \pi r \delta = 0$

Removing the $2\pi$, we have:
$r \delta = 2 r \epsilon + \epsilon h$ and
$\delta = \epsilon (2 r + h)/r$

In the infinitesimal change, the top moves down, reducing the volume, and the sides move out, increasing the volume. At the maximum volume, there will be zero overall change, so we calculate these infinitesimal volume changes and equate them.

The volume lost at the top and bottom is the top area multiplied by $\delta$, or:
$\pi r^2 \delta = \pi r^2 \epsilon (2r+h)/r$

A and the volume gained is $\epsilon$ multiplied by the area of the sides, or:
$2\pi rh \epsilon$

Therefore, cancelling $2 \pi$ and $\epsilon$, we have:
$r^2 (2r+h) / r = 2 rh$
$2r^2+rh = 2rh$
$2r+h = 2h$
so $2r = h$

The volume of a cylinder is $\pi r^2 h$, so if this is $1000 cm^3$, then replacing $h$ by $2r$, and using cm as the unit for r:

$2\pi r^3 = 1000$
$r = \sqrt[3](1000 / 2\pi) = 10\sqrt[3](1/2\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

The volume $$V = π r^2 h = 1000 \quad \text{litre (given)}.$$

$$\text{surface area } S = 2πrh + πr^2=$$

$$= 2πr\left(\frac{V}{πr^2}\right) + πr^2 = 2\frac{V}{r} + πr^2.$$

Extremising it we have

$$\frac{-2V}{r^2} + 2πr = 0 \implies r =\left(\frac{V}{π}\right)^{1/3}.$$

From this, it is very simple calculate $h = V/(πr^2)$.